# Помогите распарсить XML XMLReader'ом

Tags: php, парсер, xmlparser

Коллеги, хмлка имеет вид

```
<section name="Рюкзаки">
      <section name="Рюкзаки Deuter" />
      <section name="Рюкзаки экспедиционные">
        <sectionPropertiesList>
          <property name="Плотность внешнего материала">
            <item value="300D"/>
            <item value="210T"/>
            <item value="600D"/>
            <item value="420D"/>
            <item value="290T"/>
          </property>
          <property name="Плотность материала дна">
            <item value="600D"/>
            <item value="210T"/>
            <item value="420D"/>
          </property>
          <property name="Фурнитура"/>
          <property name="Количество ручек для переноски"/>
          <property name="Боковые кормашки"/>
          <property name="Грудная стяжка"/>
          <property name="Боковые стяжки"/>
          <property name="Противооткидочные стропы"/>
          <property name="Карманы на поясе"/>
          <property name="Узел крепления горного оборудования"/>
        </sectionPropertiesList>
      </section>
      <section name="Рюкзаки городские">
        <sectionPropertiesList>
          <property name="Для города"/>
          <property name="Плотность внешнего материала">
            <item value="300D"/>
            <item value="210T"/>
            <item value="600D"/>
            <item value="420D"/>
            <item value="290T"/>
          </property>
    ...
        </sectionPropertiesList>
      </section>
  </section>
```

Как ее распарсить через xmlreader при двух одинаковых названиях узлов?

```
$sect = array();
$this->cat = $this->reader->getAttribute('name');
$name = strtolower($this->reader->localName);
while ($this->reader->moveToNextAttribute()) {
    // здесь мы получаем атрибуты если они есть
    $sect[$name]['__attribs'][$this->reader->localName] = $this->reader->value;
}

while ($this->reader->read()) {

    if ($this->reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $this->reader->localName == 'section') {
        $name1 = strtolower($this->reader->localName);
        while ($this->reader->moveToNextAttribute()) {
            // здесь мы получаем атрибуты если они есть
            $sect[$name][$name1]['__attribs'][$this->reader->localName] = 2;//$this->reader->value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добавил структуру

Comment: код теперь добавьте

Comment: @teran как определить что элемент section содержит внутри еще section'ы?

Comment: вы в курсе что данный парсер реализует `SAX`-модель, и в чем его разница с `DOM`? вы не сможете узнать есть ли дочерние узлы, но наоборот сможете запомнить, если такие узлы уже были выше по дереву.

Comment: @teran да в курсе. Значит запоминаем localName первого узла , а потом сравниваем есть ли такой же далее, если есть то делаем его вложенным первого? Тогда как определить что закончился именно вложенный узел, а не верхний?

Comment: "стэк" можно реализовать для текущего пути